# How to do incremental load for Appflow on Demand

Tags: amazon-s3, salesforce, ondemand, amazon-appflow

I am updating record from s3 to salesforce using Appflow on demand.What property i can define in the CFT to make my appflow on demand incremental based on the s3 last modified timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no way to perform incremental data load for on-demand app flows.**

Ideally, this use-case might be fulfilled by **“Run Flow on Event”** settings under **“Flow Trigger”** option under Appflow, but this option is not available for S3 Bucket as a Source.

I found some steps that should address this requirement or similar requirement of reading only the latest file/data from the S3 bucket.

My understanding is that you would like to configure the Appflow which runs every time when there is an S3 Bucket Change Event. (**when a new file is added to the S3 bucket**)

However, as a workaround you can use the Lambda function to run the flow with **“S3 Event notification”** as a Trigger to the lambda.

The **Architecture** will be as below.

**S3 Bucket (with new events) > Lambda > Appflow**

Create a Lambda python program that runs the **“flow”** every time there is a new event in the S3 Bucket